# Need help laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel

I want to get the username in table user, of post ID in post table and return `View::make('post.index')`. I need to view in post.index blade.

```
Database
users table

id
username

post table
  id
  message
  posts_id

Post.php @models folder

    public function  posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

User.php @models folder


    public function post()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }





PostController.php @controller folder
    public function index()
        {

        $posts = Post::with('username')->get();
        return View::make('post.index')->with('posts', $posts);
        }




post/index.blade.php

        the result here
        i need to the result of author id become the username
```

Comment: Apologies in advance, but what you have written is extremely unclear.  Can you please edit so that it is more clear on the problem you want solved?

Comment: hi rayryeng thanks i update the post need help to get the author_id  to fetch the username in user table

Comment: OK, that's a bit better.  I hope someone will be able to help you.  Good luck!

Comment: what is the `userId` column in post table is that the `id` column ?

Comment: in post table author_id sir.kalhano

Comment: yap i want to get the username of author base on author_id

Answer (score 0):

for the best practices:
your model class names should be `User` and `Post`. database table names should be `users` and `posts`.

in `Post.php` file ,

```
public function  user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

in `User.php` file,

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

in your `PostController.php`

```
public function index()
{
    $user_of_the_post = Post::find(postId)->user; //replace the postId //this will return the user object of the specified post
    $user_name_of_the_author = $user_of_the_post->username;
    **pass the necessary data to the view and print and return the view**
}
```

Comment: is there `public function  user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}` method in the Post model ?

Comment: do u have matching data in the database ? :)

Comment: oh sorry for the mistake of mine. in your controller : `$user_of_the_post = Post::find(postId)->user;` I updated it :) please check